# MS Word, Find with wildcard

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

first of all I'm absolutely unexperienced in VBA. also rightnow I'm working on a project and I need to find some words in 200 MS word files. these words start with the `space` and end with a `:` (colon)

for example:
... frauuaṣ̌īmca. **yz:**; **yeŋ́h/ē.:** hātąm; **yaθā.:** ahī. vairii/ō; ...

I need to extract yz & yeŋ́h/ē. and yaθā.

I could not write any proper wildcard to select just the last word before `:` (colon)

MS Word finds everything between first and 2nd :

I tried `[!space]?:` but not always returns proper answers.
for example in this case, just return everything after / or special characters.
paiti. ratīm;; frauuarāne:; hāuuanə̄/e:; sāuuaŋhə̄e:; raθβąm:; y/aθā. ahī.

=>  ne instead frauuarāne, or /e instead hāuuanə̄/e

thanks

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: many different combinations of wildcards operators. I also replaced all spaces with another sign.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code to help us too help you

Comment: the only proper working command was [!space]?:
but not always correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we are not wizard.

Comment: @ashleedawg no, I have some hundred lines of codes to extract other data from files.

Comment: @ashleedawg every word which obviously has space at start point and ends with : (colon)

Comment: vice versa, everything before colon up to first space, ie. dnf bds jsda **ab**: cjnvj dsgd

Comment: I need to force MS Word to find a **:** then read everything from right to left up to the first space

Comment: A suitable *wildcard* Find expression is [ ^s][! ^s^13^l^t:]@:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this... since I don't know [RegEx](https://regexr.com/) off the top of my head, I did go with VBA after all;

```
Sub ExtractWords()
    Dim myArray, x, strOut As String
    myArray = Split(ActiveDocument.Content, " ") 'split doc into array by space
    For Each x In myArray
        If InStr(x, ":") > 0 Then 'if there's a colon...
            strOut = strOut & Split(x, ":")(0) & vbLf '...then get everything up to it
        End If
    Next x

    Documents.Add 'create new word document
    Selection.TypeText strOut 'dump result string to new doc
End Sub
```

Running this procedure will extract all text that begins with a space and ends with a colon, and will dump the result into a new Word document.

I suspect you have characters or spacing you're not thinking of, so it may need to be tweaked.

As always, backup your document(s) before running (and since I'm not explicitly referring to the document, it's best if there is only one open).

Comment: Love it, it works perfectly. thank you

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!  It's a handy (kind of sneaky) way to look for recurrence of a specific character... it lets `Split` do the legwork instead of manually parsing the text.

Comment: Thanksssss, it was going to make me crazy.

Comment: I could convert your result to an array and I could extract all data and statistics. Thanks a lot. you saved many hours.